# Android: change width of overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-optionsmenu

Currently I have an overflow menu which has default width:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I have tried changing the theme this way:

```
<style name="MyWorkspaceDetailTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>

</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">30dp</item>


</style>
```

but didn't got any success. Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

I was follwing this[http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html] tutorial but it did not mention way to change width

So i was also looking same answer and been searching for while, All the questions on Stackoverflow was unanswered. Finally i had to dig the developer.google.com to find out a way.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

you will find a method setContentWidth(int width) which actually does our work.

Here is the answer

```
        //.......... Something on top
        popupMenu.show();

        // Try to force some horizontal offset
        try {
            Field fListPopup = menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            fListPopup.setAccessible(true);
            Object listPopup = fListPopup.get(menuHelper);
            argTypes = new Class[] { int.class };
            Class listPopupClass = listPopup.getClass();

            // Get the width of the popup window
            int width = (Integer) listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("getWidth").invoke(listPopup);

            // Invoke setHorizontalOffset() with the negative width to move left by that distance
            listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHorizontalOffset", argTypes).invoke(listPopup, -width);
 /*********** THIS LINE DOSE OUR WORK and increases the width of OverFlow Menu ******/
            listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("setContentWidth", argTypes).invoke(listPopup, width+200);

            // Invoke show() to update the window's position
            listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("show").invoke(listPopup);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Again, an exception here indicates a programming error rather than an exceptional condition
            // at runtime
            Log.w("Soemthing", "Unable to force offset", e);
        }
```

[image]

To this == >

[image]